# Namespace undefined in Internet Explorer only?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I am using the Google Closure Library to implement a very big scale project. I have just started working on it, however I'm getting a strange error in IE8. It is the only browser that detects JavaScript errors in the page, and I cannot understand why.

[http:://www.niuzly.com/ajax/niuzly.base.js](http://www.niuzly.com/ajax/niuzly.base.js)

This is the link to the JS script used. It is using the Google JavaScript Guidelines, so it should be fairly easy to understand everything. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked JavaScript file "niuzly.base.js" does not appear to `goog.provide` the namespace. Try adding the following line below your copyright notice:

```
goog.provide('niuzly.base.renderPage');
```

You should also explicitly `goog.require` 'goog.dom`:

```
goog.require('goog.dom');
```

Comment: this is added to the top of the index.php file, as the Google guidelines indicate. The order of my provide and require statements is the same as in their notes application example.

https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial

Comment: Have you tried moving the `goog.provide` and `goog.require` statements into "niuzly.base.js" to ensure there isn't an issue with the order of execution in index.php?

Comment: On a side note, the Closure Library follows the convention of placing the appropriate `goog.provide` and `goog.require` statements in each JavaScript file so that tools such as Closure Builder can manage dependencies.

Comment: Thank you finally sorted it out you were right I missed it by accident. Thanks for the trouble! That's sorted, now I have new fun errors to deal with!

Comment: Also, for other people using the closure library. As it turns out, you can define every attribute you want with the goog.dom.createDom function, but make sure 'class','for' and any other JS native things are marked with quotes, otherwise you get an error.
Also, when you define an element with a single attribute, do not add a comma after it. I've done this by accident and it works in every browser except for IE. though it was worth mentioning.